# joystick as a mouse with Fedora

Tags: linux, xorg, mouse, joystick

I would like to use a joystick as a mouse with Fedora 12. I tried js2mouse but didn't work. Is there another solution? How should I configure the system?

Answer (score 5):

I've never tried, but [these instructions for Ubuntu](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=516709#post_message_4595956) look plausible, and mostly distribution-independent.

Add a section for the joystick in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. (If you don't have one, generate it with `Xorg -configure`.) The critical line is the `SendCoreEvents` option, which makes the joystick events move the mouse pointer. If your distribution splits up X11 drivers into separate packages, make sure you have the joystick input driver.

```
Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Joystick"
    Driver  "joystick"
    Option "Device" "/dev/input/js0"
    Option "SendCoreEvents" "true"
EndSection
```

Add a line with `InputDevice "Joystick"` to the `ServerLayout` section.

For more control, grab the utilities in the [joystick package](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=695).

Answer (score 1):

try [QJoyPad](http://qjoypad.sourceforge.net/)... it worked realy well with my joypad (it also supports joysticks)
it can autodetect your joystick, number of axes, button number, also - supports joysticks with multiple axes...

for the extended list of features look [here](http://qjoypad.sourceforge.net/#features)

I use it on Arch, but you can build it from source for Fedora.

after you install it, you should just configure the axes to act as a mouse.. you will also be able to set it's sensitivity, treshold etc...